# Can't Access Wordress homepage after changing local URL

Tags: wordpress, localhost

i recently started developing a site for my local business and it doesnt have to have a hosting and a domain. I will use this site to show my clients what they're getting and giving them choices.

Fast forward yesterday, i changed the siteurl and homepage url in phpmyadmin to make the site locally accessible, and i was accessing it though. Today my ip was changed and i changed the ip adress through phpmyadmin. Now i can access all of my pages but homepage. I can access admin panel, access categories page and all other things. But when i try to open homepage it redirects me to the old URL, what should i do?

I am using Astra theme with Elementor, Woocommercial, Cartflows etc.

Comment: Update: I tried to access it through my mobile, i can access. I tried to access it from private page it works. But cant access it through my normal web browser.

Comment: Have you deleted your cache on the systems that it doesnt load properly? It may be still trying to load information based on your old IP. You should consider dynamic dns or similar to prevent future IP address changes making this problem repeat.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, today i tried to open the site and it worked, did nothing to solve this problem. Thanks again @Aliqua

Answer (score 0):

you can go to phpmyadmin from your host.
go to "options" table. change the "siteurl" to thing you want.
but if it is true, you can do a test.
creat a new page for your home page and set that for homepage from general-option -> reading .
test that. It should be work.